# Can't load url on same tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, dom

I know a way to solve this but it's the wrong way and involves creating a new file and simply cheat.

Now the problem:

1. i have a folder with the ***index.html*** file; this file has a menu which has a `<a href="reg_interlocutor.html">`
2. in *reg_interlocutor.html* i use div's and in one of them i call the registration form:
3. this inserts the content of file *form_registo_interlocutor.html* into the div and sends the data inserted by the user to the file *reg_interlocutor.php* inside a folder called php;
4. in this file *reg_interlocutor.php*, when there is a problem with the data i use

   ```
   echo "<script>alert('blablabla.'); window.location = '../index.html';</script>";
   ```

But if everything goes ok, i want to reload index.html.
The problem is that the browser reloads index.html inside the same div i was using since **Step 2**.

Actually, the tab url stays the same: *localhost/proj/reg_interlocutor.html* every step since step_2.

I already used:

```
header('window-target: main');
header('location:../index.html');

<script>top.window.location='../index.html';</script>
window.open("http://localhost/proj/index.html","_self");
```

Can anyone help me? I understand that my code is stuck on the div and that is why the index file is open inside that div.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off by using PHP (instead of HTML) to `include` an external html file instead of doing this directly in HTML. PHP can inject the external HTML file into the final output, which results in a much cleaner result than having the user's web browser fetch the other html file (creating a second request).  This should also resolve the html loading into the `<object>` tag instead of the full page.

Comment: The "problem" is that i used Css3Menu o create the menu but it allows only to insert the menu in html files... I can probably solve that easily, what bothers me is not knowing how to solve the problem above. There must be a way and i would like to know because it has been bothering me.